# Twitter Integration issue using sharekit in ios?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, twitter, ios6, sharekit

Am using sharekit sdk for twitter sharing it is working fine before suddenly from two days it was showing problem like "There was a problem to accessing Twitter" can any one have a idea to find out solution

Answer (score 2):

Twitter recently tightened restrictions on OAuth. From the discussion (https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/16443):

- You must pass an oauth_callback value to oauth/request_token. It's not optional. Even if you have one already set on dev.twitter.com. If you're doing out of band OAuth, pass oauth_callback=oob.
- You must pass along the oauth_verifier you either received from your executed callback or that you received hand-typed by your end user to oauth/access_token.

Long story short: You must update ShareKit from the master branch, or at least pull this commit: https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/pull/692