# Sharing text with twitter

Tags: ios6, sharekit

I am using sharekit SDK for twitter and facebook sharing. It seemed to be working fine, so we delivered the product. Now, we found a problem like `There was a problem to accessing Twitter` while the Facebook sharing works fine.

I have searched and found **[this link](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/16443#comment-36618)**
and 
**[Twitter Integration issue using sharekit in ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15850095/twitter-integration-issue-using-sharekit-in-ios)**

I set the callback to my app's website. **Now I am redirecting to the website after login to the twitter through app.** I don't know how to pass an `oauth_callback` value to `oauth/request_token`.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/pull/692/files Try this link.I hope it will help you

Comment: or you can switch to shareKit 2.0 entirely.